# How to prevent Calendar in Dialogue to not make postback once clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I made a div to work as dialogue when a certain button is clicked; this div contains a Calendar; I want user to be able to select a specific date and then close the dialogue himself.

this utility is commonly used in Airlines Sites to book flights.

the problem is the Calendar makes postback once it is clicked, which is annoying to user.

I even made the div load a calendar from another page, but it gives same result ...

is there anyway to make the div lasts until the user click on [OK] button, either the div loads the calendar from the same page or from another page?

I embeded a picture of the div which holds the calendar
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What calendar control or object or library are you using here?

Hint: there are BOATLOADS of them, and thus we have no clue as to which one you are using, or working with. And they ALL BEHAVE different.

And, it's also not clear why you are not using the built-in date picker?

So, for a text box control in asp.net, the date picker feature is built in, and included for a textbox control. Thus, textbox control does not require any code, any extra JavaScript or 3rd party libraries, and really no extra effort on your part beyond that of setting the textmode of a text box to date.

Drop in a text box to the web page, and set TextMode = Date.

```
        <h3>Enter Date</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
            TextMode="Date">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

The result is this:

[image]

And the above sets the date in the text box, but does not cause nor trigger a post back.

So, as noted, there are boatloads and boatloads of date pickers you can choose from. And as above shows, you can even choose to use the built-in date picker included with asp.net. As noted, no JavaScript, or even any 3rd party libraries and code are required for above.

As above shows, no post back occurs when the user selects a date in above date popup.

## Edit: So, we are using the asp.net calendar control

The issue/problem with the asp.net calendar control is that THEY ALWAYS trigger a post back.

So, the solutions are:

Use a text box with textmode="date" as I did above. This results in a nice popup calendar, but no post backs.

Dump the current control, and use the one from jQuery.UI.

Dump the current control, and use the one from the ajaxtoolkit.

Or, consider wrapping the markup inside of update panel.

Depending on how you are launching/displaying the markup, then an update panel is probably your best choice.

Let’s assume I needed to popup 2 calendars, for a start and end date.

And I want this to be a kind of re-usable start/end date prompt system.

So, we will:

Have to popup an area with two calendars (start and end date), and the user can then select the starting date, and the ending date, and we STILL WANT the pop up to remain in view.

The above can be achieved if we adopt an update panel, and pop the div using say jQuery.UI dialog.

So, our markup becomes this:

So, let's just drop in a start date (text box), an end date (text box).

Then we have a button, and when clicked, it will pop two calendars (start date, and end date)

This markup:

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdGetDates" runat="server" Text="Get booking dates" 
        OnClientClick="popdate();return false;"
            />
    <br />
    <div style="float:left">
        <h4>Start Date Selected</h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
        <h4>End Date Selected</h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

As noted, we can use an update panel, and this will allow the calendar control to have post backs, but NOT close the dialog.

As noted, there are a "gazillion" dialog routines, but bootstrap and jQuery.UI are the most common.

Let's go with jQuery.UI.

So, the following assumes BOTH jQuery (you likely have this already), but you have to add jQuery.UI to your project.

So, now our simple div (hidden), with 2 calendars:

```
<div id="startend" runat="server" style="display: none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hStart" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hEnd" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <div style="float: left">
                <h4>Select Start Date</h4>

                <asp:Calendar ID="dtStart" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
                    <DayHeaderStyle Height="40px" />
                    <DayStyle BorderStyle="Solid"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        HorizontalAlign="Right"
                        VerticalAlign="Top" Height="40px" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" />
                    <SelectorStyle CssClass="btn-info" />

                    <TitleStyle Height="40px" />

                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="Ivory" Height="30px" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>


            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px">
                <h4>Select End Date</h4>

                <asp:Calendar ID="dtEnd" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
                    <DayHeaderStyle Height="40px" />
                    <DayStyle BorderStyle="Solid"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        HorizontalAlign="Right"
                        VerticalAlign="Top" Height="40px" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" />
                    <SelectorStyle CssClass="btn-info" />

                    <TitleStyle Height="40px" />

                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="Ivory" Height="30px" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
```

Note VERY close with above.

The design pattern is:

```
 start of your div to pop
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>

   -- everything in here - including the calendar control

 
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

 </div>   --- end of our div
```

And right after all above, we have our client-side pop div code:

```
    <script>

        function popdate() {
            console.log("start")
            var myDialog = $("#startend");
            myDialog.dialog({
                title: "Select booking dates",
                modal: true,
                width: "720px",
                resizable: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                appendTo: "form",
                dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                buttons: {
                    ok: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close');
                        $('#txtStartDate').val($('#hStart').val())
                        $('#txtEndDate').val($('#hEnd').val())
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                    myDialog.dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

            myDialog.dialog('open');

        }

    </script>
```

Our VB code behind for the 2 calendar events are:

```
Protected Sub dtStart_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtStart.SelectionChanged

    hStart.Value = dtStart.SelectedDate

End Sub

Protected Sub dtEnd_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtEnd.SelectionChanged

    hEnd.Value = dtEnd.SelectedDate

End Sub
```

Keep in mind, since this is an update panel, THEN ONLY controls inside of the panel can be changed by code behind. So, we dropped in 2 hidden fields, and that will allow other code to get/grab/use/enjoy the 2 selected values. And on dialog close, I also have some JavaScript code to copy the 2 values from the selected dates to standard text boxes - this was just for demo purposes, but it gives you multiple ways and multiple options for using the selected dates with client-side code, or you can use server-side code and use the 2 hidden field values.

[image]

Comment: I used this date-picker only because i can control the selectable dates and also i can control thr format..

Comment: Which date picker are you referring to? As I stated there's 100's of them.  So when you state "this" date picker we have zero clue as to which date picker you are talking about. Without us here knowing which date picker you are using then it is impossible to suggest a solution or help you. I mean there's the built-in one I used above.  There's a jquery.ui one. There's one from the ajaxtoolkit,  there's one from bootstrap and there's many more.  There also a aspx one in the toolbox. So what library and date picker are u using here?

Comment: I am using ASP. NET built-in Calendar control

Comment: Ok, that means the one from the toolbox, since as I stated, you can drop in a text box, set textmode="date", and you get the above built in date picker for free. And your screen capature looks NOTHING LIKE MY example which is the built in one. So, I shall assume and "guess" that you mean the calendar control from the asp.net toolbox, and thus are using the calendar control. Ok, with that assumption in mind, then we can start to address the problem/issue, and I'll post a note here when done editing my post.

Comment: Ok, so see my edit. We can't with that control NOT have a post back. So, either adopt the calendar from the ajaxtoolit, the jQuery.UI one, or adopt an update panel that surrounds the asp.net calendar control. I have posted a working example using the last suggesting (use a update panel). So, see my new edit..

Comment: Thnaks bro, it looks fine...